# How can I configure OS X server to advertise SMB over bonjour?

Tags: macos, finder, osx-server, smb, bonjour

We have an OS X mac mini server that stores/shares our files and our Time Machine backups (which is why AFP needs to be enabled).

We were having issues with AFP and network files being held open indefinitely, so we've switched to SMB for file sharing; everything is resolved in regards to that.

The current issue, is that selecting the server name in the Finder sidebar attempts to connect via AFP. So, users need to open Finder, select Go -> Connect to server, each time they want to connect. This is becoming frustrating for users who have laptops. Is there a way to advertise the SMB shares over bonjour so that the SMB connection to the server will show up in the Finder sidebar? Or another better way so that users don't have to constantly go through the menu to access their network files?

Comment: There are several other ways to do this, the most common would probably be to auto-mount the shares in System Preferences -> Users & Groups (and/or via a .mobilconfig if you have a large amount of users).  How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I usually just do shortcuts- either on the desktop or in the dock (a little more dynamic)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to add the shared volume(s), not the machine to the "Favorites" section of the Finder sidebar.

Connect to the server using the Finder menu item and mount all the volumes the user requires. Go to the machines Finder folder and you will see icons for all the mounted volumes. Drag them one by one into "Favorites". As an added bonus you will notice that when they are mounted there is an "eject" button to the right of each name.

Comment: Thanks, but I was really hoping for a way to advertise over bonjour the fact that the SMB shares exist, so that users don't have to change the workflow of selecting the server name from the Finder sidebar under Shared. Adding favorites for all of our SMB shares could be an additional 6-10 items in the Favorites section for some users.